Transform column (Group rows via labeling )on a data frame in R using gt library
I have a data frame in R that looks like this:



var
name
value




A
John
1


A
Mary
2


A
George
3


B
Nick
4


B
Jonas
5


B
Helen
6


C
Lary
7


C
Paul
8



I want to transform it in gt to look like this :



var
name
value





John
1


A
Mary
2



George
3



Nick
4


B
Jonas
5



Helen
6


C
Lary
7



Paul
8



How ca I do it using gt in R ?
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
var = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",2))
name = c("John","Mary",  
"George",
"Nick"   , "Jonas",
"Helen","Lary","Paul")    
value = c(seq(1,8,1))                 
data_=tibble(var,name,value);data_ 


You can use the arguments on the gt() function. this should work
data_ |> gt(groupname_col="var", row_group_as_column = TRUE)


can you put them in the middle  of the grouping column ?

I am not sure about it but according to the documentation it will be placed at the start of the grouping column as we have if we print dplyr group_by
